# Opening and closing boxes when a div is clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm running some jQuery on my site that opens and shuts boxes when a div is clicked.

I have the following;

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.hide-text').hide(); 
    $('.hidden_answer').hide();
    $('.show-text').click(function(){ 
        $('.hide-text').toggle(100); 
    });
    $('.home_questions_top').click(function(){
        $(this).next('.hidden_answer').slideToggle(200);
    });
```

This is the HTML structure. There are about 7 or 8 of these blocks of code in a row;

```
   <div class="home_questions_top">
       <h3>Test</h3><div class="arrow"></div> 
       <div class="clear"></div>
   </div><!--home questions top--> 
   <div class="hidden_answer">
       <p>blah blah blah blah</p>
   </div>
   <div class="closed_blue"></div>
   <div class="home_questions_bottom"></div>
```

So far, you click the top div and the "hidden answer" opens. I would like to make the jQuery a little different though, can I make it so when you open the box by clocking the top div it opens as it does now, but when you like a different div (one of the other 7 or 8 I said about) this one shuts, and that one opens. So basically only one can be open at a time?

The other idea I had is not as important but would be cool. At the moment the div class "arrow" contains a background image of arrow pointing down, it would be great to make it point up when the box is opened, maybe by rotating 180 or just switching the background image....

Any advice is welcome, thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think what you're after may look/act something like this...

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){

    $("div").click(function(){
        $("ul").each(function(){
            if( $(this).is(":visible") )
                $(this).toggle(100);
        });
        jQuery("ul", this).toggle(100);
    });
});
</script>

<div> List One
    <ul style="display:none">
        <li>element, list one</li>
    </ul>
</div>

<div> List Two
    <ul style="display:none">
        <li>element, list two</li>
    </ul>
</div>

<div> List Three
    <ul style="display:none">
        <li>element, list three</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: I'm just going to put something up and give this a shot.

Comment: @ experimentX - that site looks fantastic, never heard of it but I will save it to favorites, it's a great idea. The code you wrote works the same as mine at the moment...

Comment: @ Black Box Operations  - thanks, I will see if I can modify that to work how I need it to work. I have never used this site/forum thing before, I'm amazed by the quick response. I spend quite a bit of time on the Wordpress forum, it's good there too.

Comment: @experimentX also never seen that site before, but I will again.. upvoted and bookmarked!

Comment: @Dan @Codecraft well, this is just a fiddle good for sharing codes. See you guys around.

Comment: `$(".home_questions_top").click(function(){
        $(".hidden_answer").each(function(){
            if( $(this).is(":visible") )
                $(this).toggle(100);
        });
        jQuery(".hidden_answer", this).toggle(100);
    });`

Comment: Just tried that code above, and set .hidden answer to display:none; in my CSS file. Doesn't work though, i've tried some different combinations of code, I have tried to follow the pattern in your example with . home_questions_top being the same as "div" and . hidden_answer being "ul" - what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

*Reinventing-the-wheel* answers are the ones to avoid inside your work, but may be used when learning something new.

The best solution for you would be to use : **jquery UI Accordion**

check out these samples: http://jqueryui.com/demos/accordion/

and feel free to ask if anything is not clear yet.

Comment: jQuery Accordion would also work, looking at your site its pretty similar.  So I upvoted.

Comment: Ok, so accordion didn't work that well, it took away the bottom div and also looks really dodgy while opening. I've noticed some JQuery runs really smooth and other bits are quite "lumpy". It also put a blue ring (in safari) round my top div which looks fugly! I think I might go back to the other code. On the plus side its very, very easy to implement - if I did it right. I just linked the UI from google and used the .accordion function. Very cool, must look into the UI stuff.

Answer (score 0):

Give all of your 'close' blocks a shared class, and then when something is clicked that triggers an open, you can run some code that acts on all of the elements with that class - in your case, to close them or hide them, well, except for the one that was clicked of course.

Comment: Hi, thanks for writing. Are you saying add a class using Jquery? Then I could identify all the other ones as part of the function? My Java is truly aweful, my html, css and php isn't bad, but java.....ha

Comment: You could - but you don't have to - I was meaning <div class='myBox'></div> (and so on)... then you could use jQuery to act on everything that has 'myBox' as a class: (".myBox").doSomething()

Comment: Hi, I think that's similar to what I have, so I may be able to just modify the code i'm using? I posted the link to my site in the original post if you fancy taking a look.

Comment: I think you have had the best answers above!  Nice looking site btw.

Comment: Thanks Codecraft, it's going live soon so i'm hoping I can get it ready in time! It's taken a long time and could be a better design, sometimes I think you have to just do something though, so many ideas and so little time in the day! The Wordpress page has some cool jquery on IMO, it's not advanced but the effect it quite cool I think....only problem is the first time you see it the images arn't cached so its a bit jerky. Could do with preloading them somehow...